# How to set specific descending x axis in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Easy question; I have 2 sets of data, approx 500 entries:

```
iStart, iStop, iStep = 0.2, 100, 0.2
x = list(np.arange(iStart, iStop+iStep, iStep))
y = np.random.uniform(20,25,(500,1))  
plt.plot(x, y[::-1])
```

I want to have on the x-axis from left to right the vector x; descending. When I use there [::-1], the y values change as well.

Comment: [Invert Axes](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/invert_axes.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a Matplotlib [example](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/invert_axes.html) for doing just this.

Edit: OP asked about adjusting x-ticks... I have made a deliberately awful example to show how this works. Passing an array into `plt.xticks([100, 20, 5])` tells it which to show. Using `np.arrange(start, stop, step)` for example could give you an evenly spaced array.

### Solution

```
import numpy as np

iStart, iStop, iStep = 0.2, 100, 0.2
x = list(np.arange(iStart, iStop+iStep, iStep))
y = np.random.uniform(20,25,(500,1))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows = 1, ncols = 1)
ax.plot(x, y[::-1])
ax.set_xlim(np.max(x),np.min(x))
plt.xticks([100, 20, 5])
plt.show()
```

### Output

[image: Output]

Comment: Hey thanks; do you know also how to get more values on the x axis? There is now a gap of 20, can it be smaller?

Comment: @wecandothis I have added two lines of code to illustrate how adjusting the ticks works.